# Swift filter username array with regex

Tags: ios, swift

In my app the user can search other users by their `username`. Right now I `filter` the names like this:

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    serachingNames = userArray.filter({$0.lowercased().prefix(searchText.count) == searchText.lowercased()})
    searching = true
    theTableView.reloadData()
}
```

This works ok, but not exactly the way I want it to.
How it should work:

**Input:** 1234

**should find:** asdf1234

**Input:** _*$

**should find:** asdf_*$jkljö

How can I achieve this? Right now it only finds usernames that match from the beginning.

Comment: Wouldn't [`contains(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1414563-contains) do what you want? Maybe something like `$0.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())`?

Comment: Your examples don't make sense to me. You're saying that if the user types "1234" you should find the string "asdf1234" in that input? Seems to me that if the user inputs "asdf1234", you want to be able to find the substring "1234" inside.

Comment: @rid ,youre right, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @rid mentioned in the comments, `contains` was actually what I needed:

```
serachingNames = userArray.filter({$0.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())})
```